# Automated API blackbox testing

Tags: spring, postgresql, rest, soap, automated-tests

I have a (slightly complex) spring webservice which communicates with multiple frontends via a RESTful API (JSON) and additionally with other devices via SOAP or REST. I'd like setup an automated test environment which is capable of the following things:

1. create preconditions via fixtures (POSTGRES DB)
2. send REST or SOAP messages against the API
3. is able to run certain task (requests against the API) at a specific 
   time/date
4. assert and validate the produced results (return of the API call or 
   check the DB)
5. run all tests independet from any frontend/UI
6. integrate the testing environment in my infrastructure (i.e. create a 
   docker container which runs all tests deployed by Jenkins)

preferably I'd like to build reusable components (i.e. for creating a user that is needed in multiple different tests and so on...). I know there are a lot of tools and frameworks (SoapUI, JMETER,...). But before trying them all and getting lost, I'd like to get an experience report from someone who has a simular setup.

Answer (score 1):

we are using JMeter for API testing.  We tried SOAPui but it had some memory issues.  So we are pushing forward with JMeter and so far so good.
For your questions:

1. We are using MySQL, but this post seems to show how to set up a postgres connection in JMeter: https://hiromia.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-perform-load-testing-on.html
2. JMeter can send REST API requests
3. I'm not sure if this is possible but you could probably have your Jenkins job scheduled to run when you need the API to run the specific task at the specific time.
4. There are quite a few assertions in JMeter.  I use the Response and the BeanShell Assertions a lot.
5. JMeter is independent from any front end UI which helps pinpoint bugs.
6. I have not run docker but I am running via Jenkins.  This jenkins plugin has been helpful: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin

A few more Tips:

- Use the HTTP Request Defaults element. It will save you from having to update all your HTTP requests.
- Use the User Defined Variables to define variables you need.
- You can combine user defined variables like:  ${namePrefix}${myTime} but it will have to be in a 2nd User Defined Variable element(you cant combine them in the same element)
- If you have multiple test environments, set up a user defined variable with a value like this: ${__P(testenv,staging)}  This way, you can change it from a CLI like this: -Jtestenv=HOTFIX
- We are using ExtentReports for pretty html results reports with a custom JSR223 Listener(find my old post on this site).
- If your site uses cookies, use the HTTP Cookie Manager.
- If you need things to happen in order, on the Test Plan element, check this option: Run Threat Groups consecutively.  If you dont, JMeter runs them in a random order.

Hope this is helpful.  Happy Testing!